# Should one name a field the same name as its class?

Tags: java

Suppose you have this class:

`class Email {}`

And you want it to have a field which holds the actual email address:

```
class Email {
    String email;
}
```

The advantage of creating a sort of "wrapper class" for Emails is that you would then have a something like

`List<Email> emails` or `for (Email e : emails) {}`

instead of

`List<String> emails` or `for (String e : emails) {}`

which arguably is more readable. Furthermore, if you would, in the future, require an additional property, like `boolean isActive`, you would not have to refactor your previously written code.

However, the problem I've run into is that one must then refer to a specific email as `email.email`. This is unaesthetic and violates the DRY principle.

More generally, any time a class's name and a field's name should be the same, you will have to refer to that objects field in a repetitive way (`name.name`), which is more verbose and worse for readability.

My question: is there some kind of solution for this problem?

Comment: I think wrapping Strings for type safety is good. It doesn't violate DRY. If you don't like that naming, call the field `emailAddress` or `address`. I would also make the class immutable, otherwise you might have problems if you store it in a Set  or use it as a key in a map.

Comment: An `Email` would not contain an `email’ field but many others, which would sound less repetitive.

Comment: Add `toString()` method into your class. Which return the email.

Answer (score 0):

For objective oriented, it's better to access another object's filed by getter method, which is able to change the method name to a proper one. For example:

```java
class Email{
  String email;

  public String getEmailAdress(){
    return email;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the wrapper format like that on a regular basis. A class is a blueprint of an object which should have some properties. if you try to wrap every field with a class, then you've to create many classes for that. I don't see any problem with

> List emails or for(String e : emails) {}